React Three Fiber: Isometric Sprite Alignment
I'm creating a simple game using Isometric sprites using React Three Fiber.
Currently trying to resolve an issue on the sprites not aligning properly to their grids.
Currently this is how my sprites appear (the middle Red one is a control for a plain 1024x1024 png to gauge alignment):

This is the component handling how sprites are positioned within the Canvas Grid:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLoader, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';
import * as THREE from 'three';

interface CitySpriteProps {
  imageUrl: string;
  position: [number, number, number];
  scale: number;
  isFlat?: boolean;
  GRID_SIZE: number;
  GRID_DIVISIONS: number;
}

const CitySprite: React.FC<CitySpriteProps> = ({ imageUrl, position, scale, isFlat = false, GRID_SIZE, GRID_DIVISIONS }) => {
  const texture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, imageUrl);
  const { scene } = useThree();
  const CELL_SIZE = GRID_SIZE / GRID_DIVISIONS;

  useEffect(() => {
    let object3D;
    if (isFlat) {
      // Use PlaneGeometry for roads
      const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
      object3D = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      object3D.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
      object3D.position.set(position[0], 0, position[2]);
    } else {
      // Use Sprite for buildings
      const spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: texture });
      object3D = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
      object3D.scale.set(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, 1);
      object3D.position.set(position[0], CELL_SIZE / 2, position[2]);
    }
    scene.add(object3D);

    return () => {
      if (object3D.material) object3D.material.dispose();
      texture.dispose();
      scene.remove(object3D);
    };
  }, [texture, scene, position, scale, isFlat]);

  return null;
};

export { CitySprite };

I'm also using the react-three/drei Orthographic Camera for projection like so:
        <OrthographicCamera
          position={[100, 100, 100]}
          near={-500}
          far={500}
          zoom={50}
          makeDefault
        />

This could be down to my own misunderstanding of how isometric graphics work since this is my first time tackling one but any advise or solutions to resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
